# C# mp4 resource file high storage

Tags: c#, debugging, resources, storage, mp4

I was looking for block that way  who wants copy the mp4 files
And I'm finding the way, that i changed mp4 file to resource
By this way:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    String openVideo = @"c:\temp\video.mp4";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(openVideo, global::ProjectName.Properties.Resources.mymp4name);            
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openVideo); 
    }
```

it works!
But after the debug a software
All of the storage of that saved in the exe file and this is so heavy for a file , and is there any way to save that resourse file Separate and exe file just do the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to storage files, no matter the type you can use "FileStream".

```
private void SaveFile(string _pathToGet, string _pathToSave)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream();
    byte[] = GetFile(_pathToGet);
    fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

private byte[] GetFile(_path)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    fs = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    fs.Close();
    return data;
}
```

That's may help.

Comment: thank you i use your way but i have lots of errors like
_path does not exist data does not exist and ..
can you help me more clearly by a complete source? my exe file size is 800 mb because of mp4 resource and i want separate this to other pats and format like .dat or .resource

Comment: Can you tell me when this errors comes up? To use the code you need to specify in the path the name of the file too. Something like: `C:\\MyFolder\\MyVideos\\File.mp4` and the path to save also need's the name of the file and the extension, like: `C:\\temp\\video.mp4`. By the way, i dont recommend to save files on the "resources", hope that helps.